# Load loopback module when a source is available

Tags: pulseaudio

I want to permanently route a sound card input source to a sink output to hear it. 
To achieve this i've added the following line in `~/.config/pulse/default.pa`:

```
load-module module-loopback latency_msec=5 source=alsa_input.pci-0000_00_1b.0.analog-stereo source_dont_move=true
```

The issue is that it does not works at every boots.

My first guess is sometime the loopback module is loaded before input sources are ready (maybe `module-udev-detect` has not finished its work).

When it does not work, there are these logs:

```
Nov 17 10:13:18 localhost.localdomain pulseaudio[1127]: E: [pulseaudio] module-loopback.c: No such source. 
Nov 17 10:13:18 localhost.localdomain pulseaudio[1127]: E: [pulseaudio] module.c: Failed to load module "module-loopback" (argument: "latency_msec=5 source=alsa_input>
```

Does PA offers a straighforward way to load a module only when a source is available without having to resort on some kind of voodoo bash script ?

Comment: AFAIK the Pulseaudio CLI languages offers no way to wait for a source to become available, so I'd indeed use bash script "vodoo" via `pacmd` etc: A simple loop to wait until the source is present, then load the module. About 5 lines or so. Start via something that gets executed when you log in (depends on your system).